# Passing Functions to Spark not working with python V1.2.0

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a simple program to read data from hdfs and using map to manipulate the same, but the manipulation can't be done in single line so using method-

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def myFunc(s):
        print("TESTING------------")
        words = s.split(" ")
        return len(words)

    sc = SparkContext("local[8]")
    sc.textFile("hdfs:///stats/test.csv").map(myFunc)
```

Its simple straight forward, after the hdfs read happens , the method myFunc must be called but it never get called but it works with single line lambda-

```
csv.map(lambda x: (x.split(","), x))
```

I tried to use as its mentioned here -
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

But with python the method myFunc is getting called once in 10 times of trial.
I checked the log and couldn't find any error.

Comment: Why do you say that `myFunc` never gets called? What is the expected output and what is the output you are getting? The program you currently have in the first block won't return any values because `map()` is a transformation, and [transformations in Spark are lazy](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations). Furthermore, the program in your second block is not equivalent to the one in the first block (you're splitting on different characters, for example), so comparing them doesn't make sense.

Comment: if you notice, the snippet I provided is actually the one provided in Spark documentation example , regarding my second block of code, I just intended to show that any calculation in a single line lamBda works fine even len(...)

Comment: Where specifically in the official docs did you get that snippet from? Also, it's still not clear what output you expect and what output you got. Please explain what output you are seeing when you run the first block code and why you think it's wrong. From what I can see, the first block of code has no *actions* (as opposed to *transformations*), so it won't give any output. And that is the correct behavior.

Comment: If you try `print sc.textFile(...).map(myFunc).take(5)` or `print sc.textFile(...).flatMap(myFunc).take(5)` you should see that your function was applied just fine. `take()` is an action that actually returns results.

Comment: yeah Nick , can you please make you last comment as an answer because lazy loading was the actual reason behind.